# Alerta não funciona em um caso específico

Tags: javascript

Olá, fiz este código em um exercício para iniciante em JS.

Me ocorre um problema na função de **Alerta**. Fiz ele para que quando o usuário deixasse de inserir em algum dos campos me retornasse o alerta.
Ele funciona quando não é inserido valores em ambos (nome e idade), ou até mesmo quando eu não insiro em **nome** mas sim em **idade**... Enfim, o problema é que **se eu insiro nome mas não idade, o alerta não funciona!** assim, segue para a função abaixo, **e isso é um erro.**

```
var executar = document.getElementById("botao")

executar.onclick = function() {
    let nome = prompt('Digite seu nome')
    let idade = parseFloat(prompt('Digite sua idade'))

        if (nome === '' || idade === '') {
            alert('Preencha os dados corretamente!')
            console.log('teste')
            return
        }


        if (idade >= 18) {
            document.querySelector('#h1').innerHTML = (`Olá ${nome}, você é de maior! `)    
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#h1').innerHTML = (`Olá ${nome}, você é de menor! `)
        }
        
        if (nome.toLowerCase() == 'neo') {
            document.querySelector('#h2').innerHTML = ('Você é o Neo do Matrix!')
        }
    }
```

Tentei diversas maneiras, até mesmo separar ambos if's (um if somente condição nome e outro somente condição idade) e mudar '' para null e também undefined, mas nada... alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: `parseFloat('')` retorna um `NaN`. Faça algo mais simples como: `if (!nome || !idade) `, usando o `!`.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

O erro nesse código seria comparar um número flutuante com uma string `idade === ''`, porque antes da comparação aconteceu uma conversão de uma string para um número flutuante.

## Solução:

```js
// Update header text
document.querySelector('#t').onclick = function () {
  let nome = prompt('Digite seu nome')
  let idade = parseFloat(prompt('Digite sua idade'))
  console.log(idade)
  if (nome === '' || isNaN(idade)) {
    alert('Preencha os dados corretamente!')
    console.log('teste')
    return
  }


  if (idade >= 18) {
    document.querySelector('#h1').innerHTML = (`Olá ${nome}, você é de maior! `)
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#h1').innerHTML = (`Olá ${nome}, você é de menor! `)
  }

  if (nome.toLowerCase() === 'neo') {
    document.querySelector('#h2').innerHTML = ('Você é o Neo do Matrix!')
  }
}
```

Mais informações:

[isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)